# Hash + Salt v. Hash + Encryption

Tags: encryption, hash, salt

I was wondering if using a salt with a hash is more effective than hashing and encrypting your hash.

Comment: More effective for what use-case? Password hashing?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. They provide different things.

The reason you hash a password is so you compare it later on without ever exposing the plaintext. A salt is used to make a large collection of hashes harder to bruteforce.

Encrypting a hash does nothing to make the hash harder to bruteforce. If you're compromised to the point your hashes are leaked, there is a good chance the attacker will also be able to figure out the encryption method and the key.

Comment: Saying a salt makes a hash harder to brute force is misleading. It does *not* make brute forcing a particular hash harder, but it *can* make brute forcing a corpus of hashes harder, by tying each guess to a specific hash rather than to the corpus as a whole. Encrypting hashes does in fact make brute forcing much more difficult as long as the key is kept secret — the attacker must now brute force the key as well as the password.

Comment: @StephenTouset for sure. I misspoke.

Comment: "...able to figure out the encryption method *and the key*" You may want to edit your answer instead of just acknowledging Stephen (and, hopefully, me).

Comment: Let's just say that your server had an SQL in the passwords database. At that point, doesn't encryption do about the same thing as a salt, or even potentially more?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes edited.